# SQL Server : problem in finding values in an Json object array

Tags: json, sql-server

This is my JSON array object saved in a column

```
{
  "relationalKeys": [
    {
      "job_type": [
        "8",
        "5"
      ],
      "job_speciality": [
        "50",
        "51"
      ],
      "job_department": [
        "70",
        "71"
      ],
      "job_grade": [
        
      ],
      "job_work_pattern_id": [
        "43"
      ],
      "pay_band_id": [
        "31"
      ],
      "staff_group_id": [
        "27"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to extract records matching with such as Jobtype in (8,5). Problem is that when we use `CROSS APPLY` in a huge database, results are returned very slowly.

This is my query and its working fine, however I want to know if there any solution available to find values without referring to a particular array index i.e [0] but value can exist in anywhere in the json array.

```
SELECT Json_Value(jsonData, '$.relationalKeys[0].job_type[0]'), * 
FROM tbl_jobs_details_v2
WHERE Json_Value(jsonData, '$.relationalKeys[0].job_type[0]') IN (8, 5)
```

I want something matching in all elements of an array like adding a * but SQL Server doesn't support this.

```
SELECT Json_Value(jsonData, '$.relationalKeys[0].job_type[*]'),* 
FROM tbl_jobs_details_v2
WHERE Json_Value(jsonData, '$.relationalKeys[0].job_type[*]') IN (8, 5)
```

Comment: When you say `cross apply` is slow, do you mean `cross apply openjson`? You have to use `openjson` if you want multiple values. Perhaps `openjson with (...)` may be faster

Comment: Add the slow `CROSS APPLY` query to your question.

Comment: CROSS APPLY is bit slow when we try to join the json column so it is not working for me.

Comment: You need a `CROSS APPLY` if you want to get the job types (`8` and `5` from the example). What is the expected output?

Comment: Expected output is to include all results which are in IN clause and should't be using Cross Apply. I am trying to find a way get results directly in where clause without traversing through all the elements of json array. Because, we don;t know the index of the array where our result set is. i hope i clarify... Thanks

Comment: Saying "find a way to get results directly in where clause without traversing" and "we don't know the index of the array where our result set is" is a little contradictive.  You will have to use a cross apply with openjson as that is how you deal with json arrays in sql server.  Please edit your question and provide your cross apply attempt.  Also, based on your sample data add your expected output in table format.